# Rotate an element around a certain point (without using transform-origin) with javascript

Tags: javascript, rotation, trigonometry

I want to be able to return a co-ord of an element after it has been rotated around a certain point. This is what I have so far (but it is incorrect).

```
function rotateAroundPoint(pointX,pointY,angle) {
    //converting degrees to rads
    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180.0
    newX = Math.cos(angle) * pointX - Math.sin(angle) * pointY;
    newY = Math.sin(angle) * pointX + Math.cos(angle) * pointY;
    return({x:newX,y:newY});
}

var result = rotate(50,50,45);
/* offsetting by the result should make it look rotated around the point 50 50 */        
document.getElementById("div").setAttribute("style","top:"+(result.y)+"px;left:"+(result.x)+"px;");
```

the css:

```
 #div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
padding:10px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: red;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Here's a good explanation on how to rotate around a point other than origin: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69806.html

Comment: Not what I'm getting at! kinda hard to describe what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Any chance of getting these "final calculations".

Answer (score 1):

The CSS transform rotates around the center of the element; I understand you are looking to move the element such that it appears to be rotated around a different point. The natural way to do it would be transform-origin, but you say you don't want to do that — I'll assume you have a good reason.

What you need to do is offset the position of the element *by the amount its center would move if rotated about that point*. Therefore:

1. Let point *p* = half the width and height of the element (using `getComputedStyle`, if necessary).
2. *p* = *p* - rotation origin point.
3. *p* = *rotate*(*p*, *angle*)  (where `rotate` is the (misnamed, as it does not rotate about a point but the origin) function in your code).
4. *p* = *p* + rotation origin point
5. *p* = *p* - half-sizes of element.

*p* now contains the values to assign to top/left. Note that steps 2–4 are the normal procedure for rotating about a point other than the origin; steps 1 and 5 are simply offsetting from the default transform origin and back.

---

If this is *not* what you are looking for, then please provide a diagram showing the results you want.